# Problem uploading files, after changing domain name

Tags: uploads, media-library, permissions

I just changed my WordPress website domain name (on the same server). Everything works fine, and the paths are correct. I can install plugins and updates without any problem.

However, I can only upload media when the `wp-content` directory's permissions is set to 777. When I get it back to 755 I get an error that the file couldn't be copied to the folder.

What could cause this problem?

Comment: Sounds like permissions for the web server, maybe your web server runs as www-data then the user or group should have read permission. Se more in this Q: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/cant-upload-images-due-to-permissions-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well' for anyone that faces this problem. look here:
[plesk-permissions-wordpress](http://jonathankressaty.com/2011/11/02/plesk-permissions-wordpress-ftp/#comment-6458)